# laravel seeds unique column ignore duplicate entries

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i have a Seeder in Laravel

```
public function run()
    {
        $user = App\Admin::create([

            'first_name'     => 'first',
            'last_name'    => 'last',
            'phone'    => '',
            'email'    => 'mail@gmail.com',
        ]);
    }
```

in this  email is unique,

```
php artisan db:seed
```

when I run first time its entering records into the database, when I run again its showing duplicate entry.

```
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'mail@gmail.com' for key 'email'
```

do i have option to ignore that.?

Comment: You may have to remove unique key constraint from email column in database,

can you add you migration code of table `admins`?

Comment: the requirement is `email should be unique.` thing i am looking for is override or ignore. is that possible.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have an option to check whether the given email exists in the table or not.

```
public function run(){
            $admin = DB::table('admins')->where('email', '=', 'mail@gmail.com')->first();

            if ($admin === null) {
                // user doesn't exist
                $user = App\Admin::create([

                    'first_name'     => 'Walter',
                    'last_name'    => 'Brown',
                    'phone'    => '',
                    'email'    => 'admin@gmail.com',
                    'password' => Hash::make('Admin123'),
                    'is_active'    => 1,
                    'remember_token' => str_random(10)
                ]);
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `firstOrCreate()` method on the model like this:

```
public function run()
{
    App\Admin::firstOrCreate([

        'first_name'     => 'first',
        'last_name'    => 'last',
        'phone'    => '',
        'email'    => 'mail@gmail.com',
    ]);
}
```

If you want to insert multiple records, you can do something like this in your `run()` function:

```
$records = [
    [
        'first_name'     => 'first',
        'last_name'    => 'last',
        'phone'    => '',
        'email'    => 'mail@gmail.com',
    ],
    [
        'first_name'     => 'first2',
        'last_name'    => 'last2',
        'phone'    => '',
        'email'    => 'mail2@gmail.com',
    ]
];

foreach($records as $record) {
    App\Admin::firstOrCreate($record);
}
```

I use this trick in my seeders anytime I want to ensure no duplicate values are inserted in the DB. The `firstOrCreate()` method checks if the record is in the database before creating if it's not.

Answer (score 1):

Try refreshing the database before each run. Import with:

use Illuminate\Foundation\Testing\RefreshDatabase;

...and put this at the top of your class:

use RefreshDatabase;

(From :https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/database-testing#resetting-the-database-after-each-test)

Comment: RefreshDatabase will remove all entries right .? if that is the care we have very huge data lose. i just want the seeders to ignore if the same record already there.

Comment: Sorry, didn't realise you were seeding a table populated with important admin data - an interesting situation to be in. 
In that case I agree with all of those suggesting Faker for unique addresses, or removing the unique constraint altogether.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to populate your database is create a factory and then run seeder using that factory.

Create a factory, usually in data/factories directory:

```
$factory->define(App\Admin::class, function (Faker\Generator $faker) {
    return [
        'first_name'    => $faker->firstName,
        'last_name'     => $faker->lastName,
        'phone'         => $faker->phoneNumber,
        'email'         => $faker->email
    ];
});
```

And then run your seeder:

```
factory(Admin::class, 20)->create();
```

This example will create 20 users and store them.

Above example use Faker to generate random data, https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: What if you want to provide an array of possible values (since you need them exactly as they exist elsewhere in your app) and still need to force they are unique?

Answer (score -1):

You can solve it by 2 ways :

1) Either remove unique key constraint from email column in database (not recommended)

2) Use faker library to generate unique email address - https://github.com/fzaninotto/Faker

Comment: Does facker will override email or ignore email if already exist.?

Comment: No, this error i encounterd in production, i dont want to insert fake emails there, i am looking for a solution that either ignore email or override email.

Comment: @Sethu also fakers unique generators are (pseudo)random, it is possible for them to produce the same value twice although quite unlikely.